# Getting dashboard subscription emails for no reason?

Tags: dashboard, subscriber

I have a user getting "Dashboard Refreshed" emails -- when I check, the dashboard is configured to display data as the dashboard viewer in the dashboard properties, which would usually mean the dashboard doesn't support subscriptions. I can't even get a "Subscribe" button showing when logged in as an admin.

Furthermore, when I click to open the dashboard from the email, the dashboard says "Last refreshed 102 days ago. Refresh this dashboard to see the latest data."

How can this be possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the dashboard did indeed have subscribers. When it was set to display data as the dashboard viewer, that subscribe button was gone, so I changed the view setting and was able to remove the subscribers. The last refreshed date updated the next day as well, so there was some lag.